# How to open a directory in PHPStorm from the terminal

Tags: 16.04

Is there a way to open up a directory in phpstorm from the terminal?

```
directory .
```

to open the working directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your terminal you can use the alias of phpstorm: .

```
pstorm PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIR
```